# bayesian parameter estimation of hawkes process

Tags: bayesian, posterior, hawkes-process

I have encountered a problem of modeling event data with hawkes process. I define the intensity function as:

$$
\lambda(t) = \lambda_{0} + \alpha\cdot\beta\cdot\Sigma_{i}^{n}exp(-(t-t_{i}))
$$
where $t_{i}$ are the times of past events $X={t_{1},t_{2},...}$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two different triggering kernels.

And my problem is how to sample $\alpha$ and $\beta$ from their joint posterior distribution $p(\alpha,\beta|X)$?

If the prior of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are $Gamma$ distribution, can I use gamma-exp conjugate relation to  **separately** sample them from $p(\alpha|\beta,X)$ and $p(\beta|\alpha,X)$ ?

$$
p(\alpha|\beta,X) = p(X,\beta|\alpha)p(\alpha)
$$

$$
p(\beta|\alpha,X) = p(X,\alpha|\beta)p(\beta)
$$

where $p(X,\beta|\alpha)$ and $p(X,\alpha|\beta)$ are the exponential likelihood of events $X$